# Can't install radare2-bindings due to `error: too many arguments to function 'void r_io_section_list_visual (...)`

Tags: python, swig, radare2

I'm trying to install the radare2-bindings for Python (http://www.radare.org/r/down.html).

After cloning the project from github and running ./configure --prefix=/usr, everything seems ok python-wide on the output (errors are from languages I won't need bindings to).

```
==> Using valabind 0.9.2--1-g7281165
==> Using swig 2.0.11
Checking valabind languages support...
 - python: cc1plus: warning: command line option '-Wstrict-prototypes' is valid for C/ObjC but not for C++ [enabled by default]
yes
 - perl: yes
 - ruby: /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require': cannot load such file -- mkmf (LoadError)
        from /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
        from -e:1:in `<main>'
test_wrap.c:821:18: fatal error: ruby.h: No such file or directory
 #include <ruby.h>
                  ^
compilation terminated.
no
 - lua: test_wrap.c:709:17: fatal error: lua.h: No such file or directory
 #include "lua.h"
                 ^
compilation terminated.
no
 - go: SWIG -go: -intgosize option required but not specified
no
 - java: test_wrap.c:135:17: fatal error: jni.h: No such file or directory
 #include <jni.h>
                 ^
compilation terminated.
no
 - guile: test_wrap.cxx:730:22: fatal error: libguile.h: No such file or directory
 #include <libguile.h>
                      ^
compilation terminated.
no
 - php5: test_wrap.c:706:18: fatal error: zend.h: No such file or directory
 #include "zend.h"
                  ^
compilation terminated.
no
 - node-ffi: no
 - ctypes: yes
 - ocaml: SWIG is buggy. Please set in ocamldec.swg the following line:
#define caml_array_length swig_caml_array_length
/usr/bin/valabind-cc: 1: /usr/bin/valabind-cc: ocamlc: not found
test_wrap.cxx:741:24: fatal error: caml/alloc.h: No such file or directory
 #include <caml/alloc.h>
                        ^
compilation terminated.
no
 - cxx: yes (g++)
 - valac: yes
Supported langs:
 - ctypes
 - cxx
 - duktape
 - perl
 - python
 - valac
checking build system type... x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
checking host system type... x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
checking target system type... x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
checking for working directories... current
using prefix '/usr'
checking for c compiler... gcc
checking for c++ compiler... g++
checking for valabind... /usr/bin/valabind
checking for swig... /usr/bin/swig
checking for g-ir-compiler... /usr/bin/g-ir-compiler
Using PKGCONFIG: pkg-config
checking pkg-config flags for r_core... yes
creating ./config.mk
cleaning temporally files... done

Final report:
 - PREFIX = /usr
 - HAVE_SWIG = 1
 - HAVE_VALABIND = 1
 - HAVE_GIRCOMPILER = 1
```

However, when I try to run make on the python folder, I get the following output:

```
Build r_core -lr_core -lr_config -lr_cons -lr_util -lr_flags -lr_asm -lr_db -lr_debug -lr_hash -lr_bin -lr_lang -lr_io -lr_anal -lr_parse -lr_bp -lr_egg -lr_reg -lr_search -lr_syscall -lr_socket -lr_fs -lr_magic  
valabind-cc python r_core -NRadare -NSDB --swig -x --vapidir=../vapi ../vapi/r_core -I/usr/include/libr -lr_core -lr_config -lr_cons -lr_util -lr_flags -lr_asm -lr_db -lr_debug -lr_hash -lr_bin -lr_lang -lr_io -lr_anal -lr_parse -lr_bp -lr_egg -lr_reg -lr_search -lr_syscall -lr_socket -lr_fs -lr_magic
valabind --swig -I /usr/include/libr -x -N SDB -N Radare -x --vapidir ../vapi -o r_core.i -m r_core ../vapi/r_core --swig
NOTICE Symbol defined VALABIND_SWIG
NOTICE Adding dependency package glib-2.0
NOTICE Adding dependency package gobject-2.0
NOTICE Adding dependency package ../vapi/r_core
NOTICE Adding dependency package r_cmd
NOTICE Adding dependency package r_util
NOTICE Adding dependency package r_cons
NOTICE Adding dependency package r_anal
NOTICE Adding dependency package r_reg
NOTICE Adding dependency package r_hash
NOTICE Adding dependency package r_egg
NOTICE Adding dependency package r_asm
NOTICE Adding dependency package r_syscall
NOTICE Adding dependency package r_db
NOTICE Adding dependency package r_io
NOTICE Adding dependency package r_bp
NOTICE Adding dependency package r_debug
NOTICE Adding dependency package r_search
NOTICE Adding dependency package r_flags
NOTICE Adding dependency package r_config
NOTICE Adding dependency package r_bin
NOTICE Adding dependency package r_parse
NOTICE Adding dependency package r_lang
NOTICE Adding dependency package r_print
NOTICE Adding dependency package r_fs
NOTICE Adding dependency package r_magic
WARNING Method delete renamed to _delete (don't ask where)
WARNING Method continue renamed to cont (don't ask where)
swig -small -O -o r_core_wrap.cxx -DG_BEGIN_DECLS -DG_END_DECLS -DG_GNUC_CONST -DSWIG_PYTHON_SILENT_MEMLEAK -I/usr/include/libr -c++ -c++ -python r_core.i
r_core.i:40: Warning 302: Identifier 'RCoreAsmHitVector' redefined (ignored) (Renamed from 'vector< RCoreAsmHit >'),
r_core.i:39: Warning 302: previous definition of 'RCoreAsmHitVector' (Renamed from 'vector< RCoreAsmHit >').
r_core.i:42: Warning 302: Identifier 'RAnalRefVector' redefined (ignored) (Renamed from 'vector< RAnalRef >'),
r_core.i:41: Warning 302: previous definition of 'RAnalRefVector' (Renamed from 'vector< RAnalRef >').
r_core.i:46: Warning 302: Identifier 'RAnalRefVector' redefined (ignored) (Renamed from 'vector< RAnalRef >'),
r_core.i:41: Warning 302: previous definition of 'RAnalRefVector' (Renamed from 'vector< RAnalRef >').
r_core.i:47: Warning 302: Identifier 'RAnalRefVector' redefined (ignored) (Renamed from 'vector< RAnalRef >'),
r_core.i:41: Warning 302: previous definition of 'RAnalRefVector' (Renamed from 'vector< RAnalRef >').
r_core.i:62: Warning 302: Identifier 'charVector' redefined (ignored) (Renamed from 'vector< char >'),
r_core.i:58: Warning 302: previous definition of 'charVector' (Renamed from 'vector< char >').
r_core.i:63: Warning 302: Identifier 'charVector' redefined (ignored) (Renamed from 'vector< char >'),
r_core.i:58: Warning 302: previous definition of 'charVector' (Renamed from 'vector< char >').
r_core.i:92: Warning 314: 'print' is a python keyword, renaming to '_print'
r_core.i:322: Warning 314: 'from' is a python keyword, renaming to '_from'
r_core.i:327: Warning 314: 'from' is a python keyword, renaming to '_from'
r_core.i:584: Warning 314: 'import' is a python keyword, renaming to '_import'
r_core.i:1979: Warning 314: 'del' is a python keyword, renaming to '_del'
r_core.i:1655: Warning 453: Can't apply (RAsmOp *OUTPUT). No typemaps are defined.
r_core.i:1660: Warning 453: Can't apply (RAsmOp *OUTPUT). No typemaps are defined.
g++ -fPIC -shared r_core_wrap.cxx -DG_BEGIN_DECLS -DG_END_DECLS -DG_GNUC_CONST -DSWIG_PYTHON_SILENT_MEMLEAK -I/usr/include/python2.7 -I/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/python2.7 -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -Wformat -Werror=format-security -DNDEBUG -g -O2 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -I/usr/include/libr -o _r_core.so -lr_magic -lr_fs -lr_socket -lr_syscall -lr_search -lr_reg -lr_egg -lr_bp -lr_parse -lr_anal -lr_io -lr_lang -lr_bin -lr_hash -lr_debug -lr_db -lr_asm -lr_flags -lr_util -lr_cons -lr_config -lr_core -L/usr/local/lib -L/usr/pkg/lib -L/usr/lib/python2.7/config-x86_64-linux-gnu -L/usr/lib -lpthread -ldl -lutil -lm -lpython2.7 -Xlinker -export-dynamic -Wl,-O1 -Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions
cc1plus: warning: command line option '-Wstrict-prototypes' is valid for C/ObjC but not for C++ [enabled by default]
r_core_wrap.cxx: In function 'void delete_RListIter(RListIter*)':
r_core_wrap.cxx:7324:25: warning: statement has no effect [-Wunused-value]
   r_list_iter_free(self);
                         ^
r_core_wrap.cxx: In function 'void RIO_section_list_visual(RIO*, long long unsigned int, long long unsigned int, int, int)':
r_core_wrap.cxx:8266:57: error: too many arguments to function 'void r_io_section_list_visual(RIO*, long long unsigned int, long long unsigned int, int)'
   r_io_section_list_visual(self, addr, len, width, color);
                                                         ^
In file included from /usr/include/libr/r_fs.h:6:0,
                 from r_core_wrap.cxx:3210:
/usr/include/libr/r_io.h:396:12: note: declared here
 R_API void r_io_section_list_visual(RIO *io, ut64 seek, ut64 len, int color);
            ^
... r_core.so
Build r_bin -lr_bin -lr_util -lr_db -lr_io  
valabind-cc python r_bin -NRadare -NSDB --swig -x --vapidir=../vapi ../vapi/r_bin -I/usr/include/libr -lr_bin -lr_util -lr_db -lr_io
valabind --swig -I /usr/include/libr -x -N SDB -N Radare -x --vapidir ../vapi -o r_bin.i -m r_bin ../vapi/r_bin --swig
NOTICE Symbol defined VALABIND_SWIG
NOTICE Adding dependency package glib-2.0
NOTICE Adding dependency package gobject-2.0
NOTICE Adding dependency package ../vapi/r_bin
NOTICE Adding dependency package r_util
NOTICE Adding dependency package r_io
swig -small -O -o r_bin_wrap.cxx -DG_BEGIN_DECLS -DG_END_DECLS -DG_GNUC_CONST -DSWIG_PYTHON_SILENT_MEMLEAK -I/usr/include/libr -c++ -c++ -python r_bin.i
r_bin.i:110: Warning 314: 'import' is a python keyword, renaming to '_import'
g++ -fPIC -shared r_bin_wrap.cxx -DG_BEGIN_DECLS -DG_END_DECLS -DG_GNUC_CONST -DSWIG_PYTHON_SILENT_MEMLEAK -I/usr/include/python2.7 -I/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/python2.7 -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -Wformat -Werror=format-security -DNDEBUG -g -O2 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -I/usr/include/libr -o _r_bin.so -lr_io -lr_db -lr_util -lr_bin -L/usr/local/lib -L/usr/pkg/lib -L/usr/lib/python2.7/config-x86_64-linux-gnu -L/usr/lib -lpthread -ldl -lutil -lm -lpython2.7 -Xlinker -export-dynamic -Wl,-O1 -Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions
cc1plus: warning: command line option '-Wstrict-prototypes' is valid for C/ObjC but not for C++ [enabled by default]
r_bin_wrap.cxx: In function 'void delete_RListIter(RListIter*)':
r_bin_wrap.cxx:6034:25: warning: statement has no effect [-Wunused-value]
   r_list_iter_free(self);
                         ^
r_bin_wrap.cxx: In function 'void RIO_section_list_visual(RIO*, long long unsigned int, long long unsigned int, int, int)':
r_bin_wrap.cxx:6271:57: error: too many arguments to function 'void r_io_section_list_visual(RIO*, long long unsigned int, long long unsigned int, int)'
   r_io_section_list_visual(self, addr, len, width, color);
                                                         ^
In file included from r_bin_wrap.cxx:3117:0:
/usr/include/libr/r_io.h:396:12: note: declared here
 R_API void r_io_section_list_visual(RIO *io, ut64 seek, ut64 len, int color);
            ^
... r_bin.so
... r_asm.so
```

Does anyone know how to solve this? I've had a lot of problems during this installation already, and was able to solve them... but this one really got me stuck now.

Comment: which operating system are you on? I don't see an error in the make output, only warnings

Comment: Linux Mint 17.2. There are a few "error: too many arguments to function" in there, actually.